# Show and hide text area on selected option change

Tags: javascript, jquery, gsp

I need a text area which should display only when both radio buttons are selected like if I select both value=1 in first case and value=2 in second case. In other cases text area should disappear. Hope someone can help. Thanks.

```js
<div class="row top-margin" id="remote">
     <g:if test="${remote?.id == 1}">
<input type="radio" required name="remote" value="1" checked > <l:lookupLabe lookup="remote" id="1"/>
<input type="radio" required name="remote" value="2" > <l:lookupLabel lookup="remote" id="2"/>
     </g:if>
     <g:elseif test="${remote?.id == 2}">
<input type="radio" required name="remote" value="1" > <l:lookupLabel lookup="remote" id="1"/>
<input type="radio" required name="remote" value="2" checked > <l:lookupLabel lookup="remote" id="2"/>
     </g:elseif>
     <g:else>
<input type="radio" required name="remote" value="1" > <l:lookupLabel lookup="remote" id="1"/>
<input type="radio" required name="remote" value="2" > <l:lookupLabel lookup="remote" id="2"/>
     </g:else>
</div>
      

<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6" id="ref">
     <g:if test="${ref?.id == 1}">
<input type="radio" required name="ref" value="1" checked > <g:message code="default.yes.label"/>
<input type="radio" required name="ref" value="2" > <g:message code="default.no.label"/>
     </g:if>
     <g:elseif test="${ref?.id == 2}">
<input type="radio" required name="ref" value="1" > <g:message code="default.yes.label"/>
<input type="radio" required name="ref" value="2"  checked  > <g:message code="default.no.label"/>
     </g:elseif>
     <g:else>
<input type="radio" required name="ref" value="1" > <g:message code="default.yes.label"/>
<input type="radio" required name="ref" value="2" > <g:message code="default.no.label"/>
     </g:else>
</div>
     </div>    

<div id=divtext style='display:none'>  <textarea id="txt1"  name="title" > </textarea></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

With javaScrip you would do something like:

`var radio1 = document.getElementsByName('ref1');
var radio2 = document.getElementsByName('ref2');`

```
if (radios1.checked && radio2.checked) {
    // do whatever you want with the checked radio
    // in this case will be display the textarea

    document.getElementById('txt1').style.display = 'block';
}
```

I hope I help.